# In Wordpress can child pages get same page template as parent?

Tags: wordpress

how to assign parent page template to its child pages dynamically ? 
Thanks

Comment: Hi Krishnendu. You should post this question on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

As you choose template for Parent page similarly choose template for child page too...